# Fields allignment not showing properly in lightning

Tags: lightning

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Here i am trying to show the field names on top and bottom field values. But some how it is having issue with alignment. Can someone suggest what is the issue here.

Component.JS

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" controller = " CustomController" >
<aura:attribute name="brokerFields" type="String[]" default="Name,Customer_ID__c,Phone,Industry,Type"/>
<aura:attribute name="field1set" type="String[]" default="field0,filed1,field2,field3"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordid1" type="id"  />
<aura:attribute name="ContactList" type="Contact[]" />
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
```

-->

```
            </div>
        </lightning:recordForm>
 <!--   </p> -->
</lightning:card>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The most likely explanation its something to do with the inbuilt styling of either lightning:card or lightning:recordForm.  I would advise inspecting the html in chrome and turning off css properties related to those built in lightning cmps.

Comment: Hi @CalvinOKeefe, I tried with inspecting also. But it did not figured out anywhere.

Comment: Its possible that the wrapper you are putting it in is too small for 5 columns, do you need to display all 5 columns on the same line?

Comment: Yes, I want to display all 5 in same columns @calvin

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated your issue in the builder screen (wide section):

[image]

In the builder on the narrow section it actually displays well:

[image]

However once I was actually on the full page after saving it displayed properly (wide section)

[image]

The narrow section on full view also displays as it does in the builder.

Mobile also appears to work

Is your image from the builder or actually viewing the page outside of the builder.

here is the component I used without any additional modifications:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" default="['Name','AnnualRevenue','Industry','Phone','BillingStreet']" />
    <lightning:card title="Member basic info">
        <lightning:recordForm
            recordId=""
            objectApiName="Account"
            mode="readonly"
            fields="{!v.fields}"
            columns="5"
        />

    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

here is the responsive view:

[image]

Seems like a css issue (bug or something) in the builder only (pending additional information from you)